# What does “foo = (foo + 1) % bar” exactly do?

Tags: objective-c

From the Finch audio library:

```
- (void) play
{
    [[sounds objectAtIndex:current] play];
    current = (current + 1) % [sounds count]; // this line here...
}
```

I try to grok it: There is a number of sounds *n*, and `current` is increased by 1 on every iteration. As soon as `current` is bigger than number of sounds *n*, the modulo returns zero. That way, it starts from the beginning.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's right.